# Infimum of a union of sets

Tags: real-analysis

Considering the set

$ A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{1}{n}, n-\sqrt n] $

I am trying to prove that $\inf(A) = 0$ but for $ \epsilon = \frac{1}{4}$ it seems there is not an element $x \in A$ such that $x$ is smaller than $\inf (A) + \frac{1}{4}$ but larger than $0$.

Does this mean that the infimum cannot be $0$? Perhaps I am confused by the definition. Thanks for the help. And as a side note, does the set $(0,0]$, which is clopen, contain the point $0$?

Comment: When $n=1$, you have the set $(0,0]$. What, exactly, is in this set?

Comment: The set $(0,0]$ should be considered empty.

Comment: I'm not sure if clopen sets of that form contain the point or not.

Comment: aw ok thus the source of my confusion.

Comment: When $n=1$, the corresponding set it $(0,0]=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:0<x\leq 0\}$ which is absurd.

Comment: To roughly quote George Orwell, "all zeros are equal, but some zeros are more equal than others"

Comment: Considering the set $(0,0]$ to be empty as suggested, I don't think $\inf(A)=0$. I think a better guess would be: $\inf(A)= \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Take $x \in ( \frac{1}{2}, 2- \sqrt{2})$. Then: $x> \frac{1}{2}$ $\Rightarrow$ $x>\frac{x+\frac{1}{2}}{2} > \frac{1}{2}$. Then for any $x \in (\frac{1}{2}, 2- \sqrt{2})$ $\exists$ $y \in (\frac{1}{2}, 2- \sqrt{2})$ such that $x>y> \frac{1}{2}$. Then $\frac{1}{2} = \inf(\frac{1}{2}, 2- \sqrt{2})$.

Then $\inf(A) = \frac{1}{2}$, since given $y \in A$, $y \geq x$ for some $x \in (2, 2- \sqrt{2})$.